# I need to show calculation result in previous table cell

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery percentage calculator which is working using `.closest('td')`. I need to show the result in the previous table cell `<td>`.

```js
$(document).on("change keyup blur live", "input", ".change-calculator", e => {
  let $td = $(e.currentTarget).closest('td');
  let from = Number($td.find('.calc-from').val());
  let to = Number($td.find('.calc-to').val());
  let result = ((to - from) / from) * 100;
  $td.next().find('.calc-result').text(result.toFixed(2));
  $td.next().find('.calc-result').val(result.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="abcde-table" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Result</th>
      <th>Calculator</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="calc-result">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="change-calculator calc-from" value="1500"><br>
        <input type="text" class="change-calculator calc-to" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's three issues in your code. Firstly the event delegated signature of `on()` needs three arguments, not four. Remove the first one, as the `input` event is all you need.

Secondly, the `.calc-result` input is in the `td` previous to the current one so use `prev()`, not `next()`.

Lastly, the `input` only has a value, so remove the line setting its `text()`.

```js
$(document).on("input", ".change-calculator", e => {
  let $td = $(e.currentTarget).closest('td');
  let from = Number($td.find('.calc-from').val());
  let to = Number($td.find('.calc-to').val());
  let result = ((to - from) / from) * 100;
  $td.prev().find('.calc-result').val(result.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="abcde-table" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Result</th>
      <th>Calculator</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="calc-result" readonly />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="change-calculator calc-from" value="1500" /><br />
        <input type="text" class="change-calculator calc-to" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```